# How to move webView cache to SD?

Tags: android, caching, webview

I've seen some apps like dolphin browser (not the HD version, the normal one) utilizing a cache-to-sd for webview but i can't seem to figure out how to do this, does anyone know how to do this or point me in the right direction? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the `WebSettings` object has a number of `set...Path()` methods. It is unclear if any of them are for the actual cache. There is also the `CacheManager` object, which has a bunch of static methods related to the cache, but no obvious way to change the cache location.

Comment: I couldn't find any answers via a google search either, but i'm really wondering how others managed to successfully move their cache entirely from the internal memory device to the sd card. Do have any other ideas?

Comment: Yes, `ws.setAppCachePath(cachedir)` exists, but all it does is to create an empty `/cachedir/ApplicationCache.db` file. I don't know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the article which describes exactly how to change webview cache storage to use sd card:
http://www.devahead.com/blog/2012/01/saving-the-android-webview-cache-on-the-sd-card/

I've already tested it in my application and it has proven to work.

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {
    // ...

    @Override
    public File getCacheDir() {
        // NOTE: this method is used in Android 2.2 and higher
        File cachePath = this.getExternalCachePath();
        return cachePath != null ? cachePath : super.getCacheDir();
    }

    private File getExternalCachePath() {
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
            File externalStorageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            // {SD_PATH}/Android/data/com.package.name/cache
            File extStorageAppCachePath = new File(externalStorageDir, "Android" + File.separator + "data" + File.separator + this.getPackageName() + File.separator + "cache");

            return extStorageAppCachePath;
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public class SomeWebViewActivity extends Activity {
    // ...

    @Override
    public File getCacheDir() {
        // Android 2.1 and lower
        return this.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir();
    }
}
```

Comment: On some devices (e.g., Samsung), `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` points to an INTERNAL SD partition. Yeah, not very logical, but it is.

Comment: @LuisA.Florit Some people already asked questions how to get a path to the external storage on samsung devices, but answers are very hacky and may not work on some devices: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524105/how-could-i-get-the-correct-external-storage-on-samsung-and-all-other-devices