# How could i get the correct external storage on Samsung and all other devices?

Tags: android

The official method Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() seems to be not working on Samsung devices...

It return "/sdcard/" but not the real path "/sdcard/external_sd/", you could refer to the following post

[Android SD Card Characteristics on Samsung Galaxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210154/android-sd-card-characteristics-on-samsung-galaxy)

Is there another methods to detect the external real storage path and suitable for all devices ?? or just teach me how to avoid this issue ??

Thanks.

Comment: such kind of non-standard implementation would ultimately kill the platform!

Comment: In my case, I have to add toLowerCase() because Galaxy S2 returns "samsung", not "Samsung"

Comment: See my answer here:

[Code to get all storages on Android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156649/is-there-a-documented-way-in-android-2-x-to-inspect-multiple-sd-cards-for-cont/18870968#18870968

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could you not try something like:

```
  String url = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
  if(android.os.Build.DEVICE.contains("Samsung") || android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER.contains("Samsung")){
            url = url + "/external_sd/";
  }
```

Comment: I guess its the only way, thanks. I really hate Samsung devices, lots of exceptions for developer =_="

Comment: @Bludell: If user rename the external_sd folder means,then we cant use url like this.

Comment: For new versions of Android this does not work either: it's `/storage/extSdCard`. WHY, SAMSUNG??????

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() return File but not String

Answer (score 9):

I hope the code below is helpful. That code finds the path of removable external storage (i.e. SD card).

```
        File file = new File("/system/etc/vold.fstab");
        FileReader fr = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {
            fr = new FileReader(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        try {
            if (fr != null) {
                br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                String s = br.readLine();
                while (s != null) {
                    if (s.startsWith("dev_mount")) {
                        String[] tokens = s.split("\\s");
                        path = tokens[2]; //mount_point
                        if (!Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().equals(path)) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    s = br.readLine();
                }
            }            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fr != null) {
                    fr.close();
                }            
                if (br != null) {
                    br.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to get all external storage paths, you can use [**ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#getExternalFilesDirs(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)) :

```
      final File[] appsDir=ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(getActivity(),null);
      final ArrayList<File> extRootPaths=new ArrayList<>();
      for(final File file : appsDir)
        extRootPaths.add(file.getParentFile().getParentFile().getParentFile().getParentFile());
```

The first one is the primary external storage, and the rest are supposed to be real SD-cards paths.

The reason for the multiple ".getParentFile()" is to go up another folder, since the original path is

```
.../Android/data/YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME/files/
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there another methods to detect the external real storage path and suitable for all devices ?

No. Android supports one "external storage real path" via the SDK. In the case of these Samsung devices, there is more than one "external storage". There is no SDK-supplied way to get at any other storage paths.

Answer (score 0):

iF you are making an application particularly for Samsung galaxy then the solution provided by Blundell is the best. However, you must ensure that all samsung galaxy tablets/handheld devices share a common directory structure. For example, in certain samsung devices (with lower storage specs), you may not be able to find /mnt/sdcard/external_sd; rather you would have to consider /data as internal storage and /mnt/sdcard as external storage. Moreover, it is not guaranteed that all samsung devices will have the same common directory structure that you are hard-coding. So, just ensure that you check directory structures of different samsung devices. If you are making a universal application (for all Android devices), then I am afraid that this approach won't work unless Android provides an API or the manufacturer comes with its own API like Motorola External Storage API that you can find here http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/library/motorola-external-storage-api/. Good luck