# How to detect that file is located on SD card?

Tags: android, usb, sd-card

Is there any durable way to detect that is file located somewhere on external (detachable/dismountable) storage?

For sure there's a way to parse file path and extract `file:///sdcard` string, but as we know on some devices this path can be different, e.g. `file:///mount/sdcard` or `file:///sdcard`, not saying that some modern devices support USB host mode, so file easily can be placed on usb stick attached to device.

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly you want existense of a known file?

Comment: @ingsaurabh depending on either file located in dismountable media or not, I plan to intercept media detaching broadcast and warn user about possible unavailability of particular file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a location of external storage via [`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) and then compare it to the path of your file. Make sure you have the [absolute path](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath%28%29) to your file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156649/is-there-a-documented-way-in-android-2-x-to-inspect-multiple-sd-cards-for-conte/6156812#6156812